# Unable to access AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am unable to access an AWS AMI instance even after setting the inbound rules to allow all traffic:

[image]

I get this error:

```
This site can’t be reached
X.XX.XXX.XX refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you say "unable to access", what command are you using and what is the error message?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, updated to show error. I am not using any command, just using the browser.

Comment: It appears that you are attempting to access a website via HTTP? Are you running a web server on the instance? (You need to install one before it can serve traffic.) Can you connect to the instance via SSH? If so, you can login and then run `curl localhost` to see if the web server is responding.

Comment: Are you using any kind of firewall rules?

Comment: You have to provide exact detals of your instance? You haven't even provided what OS are you using? What about VPC settings, subnets settings?

Comment: Does the subnet in which you launched the instance have a route to an internet gateway in it's route table?

Comment: @user308827 are you able to ssh into the system?

Comment: Almost definitely in a private subnet. Nobody new to AWS will bother trying to set up NAT gateways 

Answer (score 3):

I would:

1. Make sure your inbound rules are as you shown and that your outbound rules do allow all traffic to exit.
2. In the **EC2 Dashboard** click on the **Instances (running)** and then click on the **Instance ID**. Click on the **VPC ID** for that instance and then on **Main network ACL**. Click now on the **Network ACL ID** and confirm your Inbound rules, Outbound rules and Subnet associations. Make sure nothing here is blocking access. By default the Inbound and Outbound rules will allow all traffic and all subnets will be there.
3. You do not say so, but I imagine you have SSH access to the instance. Make sure HTTP and HTTPS services are running and listening for connections on the interface IP address and not on 127.0.0.1; something like this:
   [image]
4. Make sure IPtables is not blocking access. If you have existing rules you may want to clear them so that they look like:
   [image]
5. Run tcpdump and look for traffic on ports 80 or 443
   [image]
6. If still not working... make sure you are accessing the right IP address; If you're not using an elastic IP and your restarted the instance it will have a new public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Is your EC2 on a VPC that permits public IP addresses? This can commonly happen when you have accidentally attached the EC2 to a private VPC.

If this is the case make an AMI of the EC2 and re-create it on the public VPC.

Edit:... I had perhaps assumed the issue was simpler than it might be, Dan M explains how to ensure that the HTTP and HTTPS daemon are running, but you could also confirm that it's working "correctly" by running `curl http://localhost` from the EC2 itself... if this returns the HTML you're expecting then I would recommend going to AWS VPC Network Reachability Analyzer - https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=eu-west-2#ReachabilityAnalyzer (but you'll need to select the correct region obvs) and create a "path" to test, when this fails (assuming it fails) the report should tell you everything you need to know, and if you're unsure about how to interpret this, post it in here.

[image]

NB: perhaps create a path from the internet gateway to the network interface on your EC2 webserver, and define the `Destination port - optional` as `80`.

Answer (score 0):

**If this is a NAT instance, you must stop source / destination checking. A NAT instance must be able to send and receive traffic when the source or destination is not itself.**

[image: Source / destination check]
[image: Stop checking]

Comment: No, this is incorrect. The stop source / destination check only applies in a case like this: Instance <-> NATInstance <-> Internet. When Instance sends data to the Internet, the NAT instance will rewrite the source address to its own address and when the Internet replies, the NAT instance will rewrite the destination address to the address of Instance. When you check the "stop source / destination check" you are essentially saying to the NAT instance "go ahead and process packets where the destination IP address is not an IP address in one of my interfaces". Get it?